# RoboVM Studio - LibGDX - UnsatisfiedLinkError - IOS Simulator Doesn't Work?

Tags: ios, libgdx, simulator, unsatisfiedlinkerror, robovm

*I am using Mac. I created a game project in LibGDX. I import the project to RoboVM Studio. It is running in Desktop & Android Modes, but when I try to run the IOSLauncher, it gives me that error message:*

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> org.robovm.rt.bro.Dl.open(Ljava/lang/String;)J at
> org.robovm.rt.bro.Dl.open(Native Method) at
> org.robovm.rt.bro.Runtime.getHandle(Runtime.java:260) at
> org.robovm.rt.bro.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:187) at
> org.robovm.rt.bro.Bro.bind(Bro.java:56) at
> org.robovm.objc.ObjCRuntime.<clinit>(ObjCRuntime.java:43) at
> org.robovm.objc.ObjCObject.<clinit>(ObjCObject.java:57) at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195) at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

*When I added a "RoboVM iOS Configuration" from Run/Edit Configurations, this time it gave me that error message:*

```
> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':html:compileGwt'.
> > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
> finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the 'html' part from the settings.gradle file.
2. In build.gradle file, remove the section project(":html") completely. Keep other sections intact.
3. Save, sync with gradle, clean and build.